# ATmega4808 32 Pin - Pin PA0 doesn't get set HIGH

Tags: c, avr, atmega, microchip

I'm using an ATmega4808 32 Pin. I have 2 LEDs connected to the pins PA0 and PA1. I want to set both high. Unfortunatly only the PA1 LED is on.

I figured out the PA0 Pin could be set to EXTCLK by default. If this is the problem i can't find the solution to change the port to GPIO.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    PORTA.DIRSET = PIN0_bm; // Config PA0 as output
    PORTA.DIRSET = PIN1_bm; // Config PA1 as output

    PORTA.OUTSET = PIN0_bm; // Set Pin PA0 to HIGH 
    PORTA.OUTSET = PIN1_bm; // Set Pin PA1 to HIGH 

    while(1){
    }


    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: what are the definitions for `PIN0_bm` and `PIN1_bm`? some sort of `#define` I suppose..

Comment: It's defined in avr/io.h
#define PIN0_bm 0x01
#define PIN1_bm 0x02

Comment: How bout setting the pin functionality via the `PORTMUX` register? Family datasheet shows that PA0-PA3 have USART0 functionality by default

Comment: Correspondig to ATmega3208/4808 – 32-pin Data Sheet, the default setting of PA0 should be EXTCLK as seen in 3. Pinout -> 3.1 32-pin QFN/TQFP. As I said, PA1 works fine.

Comment: Yeah I see that, I don't see how to disable this function though. The family datasheet says *"This GPIO pin is automatically configured for EXTCLK if any peripheral is requesting this clock"* in section 9.3.4.2.2 perhaps that might be the problem

Comment: Thats what i thought. Any idea how to change this?

Comment: I'm just scrapping the surface here so it's hard to say which peripherals might be requesting this clock by default. I'd go through a process of elimination or just disable all the peripherals not being used.

Comment: Could you read CLKSEL fuse bit value?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of PIN0 is lost by writing again to registers `PORTA.DIRSET` and `PORTA.OUTSET`.

Try using `| (bitwise OR)` to not discard PIN0 config:

```
    PORTA.DIRSET  = PIN0_bm; // Config PA0 as output
    PORTA.DIRSET |= PIN1_bm; // Config PA1 as output

    PORTA.OUTSET  = PIN0_bm; // Set Pin PA0 to HIGH
    PORTA.OUTSET |= PIN1_bm; // Set Pin PA1 to HIGH
```

Or, to set them at the same time:

```
    PORTA.DIRSET = PIN0_bm | PIN1_bm; // Config PA0 and PA1 as output

    PORTA.OUTSET = PIN0_bm | PIN1_bm; // Set Pin PA0 and PA1 to HIGH
```